# Select visible pixels in a layer

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm writing a Photoshop script using JavaScript where I need to select all visible pixels in a layer to apply an effect on another layer.

The selection I need is the same as when you control+click on a layer thumbnail.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665405/how-to-load-a-selection

Comment: I tried this already but it doesn't work. @RoiS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are after is this:

```
var id1268 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
var desc307 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id1269 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref257 = new ActionReference();
var id1270 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
var id1271 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
ref257.putProperty( id1270, id1271 );
desc307.putReference( id1269, ref257 );
var id1272 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
var ref258 = new ActionReference();
var id1273 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
var id1274 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
var id1275 = charIDToTypeID( "Trsp" );
ref258.putEnumerated( id1273, id1274, id1275 );
desc307.putReference( id1272, ref258 );
executeAction( id1268, desc307, DialogModes.NO )
```

Which will make a selection of all current pixels in the current layer (like pressing CTRL)

Comment: It does select all visible pixels in a layer but it doesn't work with all layers like shapes. But still very useful if you convert shapes into pixels. Thank you.

Comment: That's another question :)